# Не могу понять причину ошибки Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Less_VisitorReplacing

Tags: php

Ошибка проявляется не всегда, чаще после очистки кеша сайта. Бывает 5 проходов по сайту нормально, на 6 выскакивает ошибка. Жмем обновить страницу, ошибка пропадает открывается страница.

Кусок кода на который ругается.

```
class Less_Visitor{

    var $methods = array();
    var $_visitFnCache = array();

    function __construct(){
        $this->_visitFnCache = get_class_methods(get_class($this));
        $this->_visitFnCache = array_flip($this->_visitFnCache);
    }

    function visitObj( $node ){

        $funcName = 'visit'.$node->type;
        if( isset($this->_visitFnCache[$funcName]) ){

            $visitDeeper = true;
            $this->$funcName( $node, $visitDeeper );

            if( $visitDeeper ){
                $node->accept($this);
            }

            $funcName = $funcName . "Out";
            if( isset($this->_visitFnCache[$funcName]) ){
                $this->$funcName( $node );
            }

        }else{
            $node->accept($this);
        }

        return $node;
    }

    function visitArray( $nodes ){

        array_map( array($this,'visitObj'), $nodes);
        return $nodes;
    }
}



/*
 * Replacing Visitor
 *
 * @package Less
 * @subpackage visitor
 */
class Less_VisitorReplacing extends Less_Visitor{



    function visitArray( $nodes ){

        $newNodes = array();
        foreach($nodes as $node){
            $evald = $this->visitObj($node);
            if( $evald ){
                if( is_array($evald) ){
                    self::flatten($evald,$newNodes);
                }else{
                    $newNodes[] = $evald;
                }
            }
        }
        return $newNodes;
    }

    function flatten( $arr, &$out ){

        foreach($arr as $item){
            if( !is_array($item) ){
                $out[] = $item;
                continue;
            }

            foreach($item as $nestedItem){
                if( is_array($nestedItem) ){
                    self::flatten( $nestedItem, $out);
                }else{
                    $out[] = $nestedItem;
                }
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }

}
```

Comment: очевидно `Less_VisitorReplacing` объявлено где-то ещё в коде, скорее всего в другом файле, который подтянут автозагрузчиком или вручную

Comment: это я понимаю ,  пробывал делать через include_once не помогает.. какие еще решения есть?

Comment: если бы этот файл инклудился бы еще раз, то ругался бы на первый класс а не второй. речь про то, что у вас есть класс с этим же именем в другом файле, а не про инклуд. Ищите по `class\s+Less_VisitorReplacing` по всему проекту

Comment: окей нашел я еще один файл где объявлен этот клас, как теперь исходя из этих 2 файлов устранить ошибку? я в php не силен , если можно разжуйте пожалуйста

Comment: @VACUUM_scm хорошо когда в проекте нет классов с одинаковыми именами, лучше просто переименуйте их. Если же код в классах один и тот же оставьте какой-нибудь один из них